# Why can't I install the latest iOS 17 beta for developers on my devices?

Tags: ios

I don't get the Beta Downloads options on my iOS device under software updates, no matter what I try.

I'm a registered and paying developer, have enabled developer mode on my iPhone XR running iOS 16.5., am logged in with my Apple ID which is also my developer ID (has the same email).

I have reset my device. Nothing helps and I don't know why.

When I manually install the IPSW iOS 17 file on my iPhone XR I first get the message that there is an update that needs to be installed first, and then it shows a loading screen. After a short moment it says it cannot be installed. No descriptive error message.

I was in another European country during the first install tries. Now I'm back in my home country where my Apple ID is also connecte to. I don't know if that disturbed something.

Any more ideas?

Comment: What, specifically, happens if you try?

Comment: Updated the question: I don't get the Beta Downloads options on my iOS device under software updates, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that option would not be there, but it's clear that there's some kind of server-side check that can enable it. At first it's not there, then after a few seconds it appears for me. If you don't see it then something's not working with that check. It could be blocked by a firewall, or Apple rejecting it based on your location or account status, or it could just be a bug.

In the meantime you can download betas from [Apple's developer download page](https://developer.apple.com/download/), which should be open to any Apple developer account.

Comment: I've installing the downloaded betas. When I manually install the IPSW iOS 17 file on my iPhone XR I first get the message that there is an update that needs to be installed first, and then it shows a loading screen. After a short moment it says it cannot be installed. No descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with the iOS 17 beta .ipsw file. I was able to update to the latest iOS 17 beta Over the Air after logging in with my developer apple ID on the device, and enabling beta software updates in Settings > General > Software Updates on the device. You may also need to enable Developer Mode on the device as well.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't find beta update in system. Finally, I installed successfully in this way. Hope to help you.

1. First download the IPSW file to the iMac
2. Connect your phone with iMac
3. Go to Finder, find your device
4. Go to the general tab, find software
5. Touch Option + Check for Update
6. Choose the IPSW file
7. Waiting update
   [You can see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3W0M.png)